# Sane ways to do a .spec file for insane big software

Tags: linux, makefile, specifications

I'm trying to make a spec file (rpm) for a insanely big software. The compile process takes about 5 hours and I don't want to review the spec file for installed files every 5 hours.

Is there a tool for generating spec files? I am not concerned about the dependencies as I can set them manually.

Comment: What you can do — and what projects like linux distros also do — is use multiple .spec files operating on the same set of source files (tarballs, patches, etc.), compiling different parts and/or with different options to, 1. reduce the turnover time to inspect potential failures, 2. introduce more parallelity during build, 3. be able to bootstrap. E.g.: avahi-{glib2,mono,qt4,}.spec in openSUSE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rpmdev-newspec` will give you the skeleton of a spec file. From there you can tune the various sections. You'll find copious amounts of `--short-circuit` useful, but do make sure that it builds cleanly from beginning to end at least once.

Comment: i had already done some specs in the past but every time i need at least launch the rpm build command several times(and compile the code several times, there is a way to detect the (future) installed files  and make a list of files to the install and files section of the spec

Comment: The thing of it is that if a package is complex enough to need to be automated, then it's usually too complex to automate. Once you complete each of the steps (`-bc`, `-bi`) you can use `--short-circuit` to start at the next step assuming they don't do anything destructive (which they shouldn't; destructive operations should only happen in prep and compile).